# Secure uploaded files on build SpringMVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have a SpringMVC WebApp and it has file upload system. 
The problem is that whenever i rebuild the project all of the files in myproject/src/main/webapp/resources/uploads disappear.

Any idea on what i can do to amend this?
I tried to look for a way to secure that folder but can't get it to work.

What i have tried POM.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
....

<!--                      <webResources> -->
<!--                        <resource> -->
<!--                          this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
<!--                          <directory>src/main/webapp/resources/uploads</directory> -->
<!--                          there's no default value for this -->

<!--                        </resource> -->
<!--                     </webResources> -->
                    <webResources>
                         <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>**</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>src/main/resources/**</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>src/main/webapp/resources/**</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </resource>
                          </resources>
                    </webResources>

                     <packagingExcludes>                        
                        WEB-INF/../resources/,
                        resources/,
                        resources/uploads/,
                        WEB-INF/classes/uploads/**,
                        WEB-INF/classes/**

                      </packagingExcludes>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: This looks like the build is configured to delete from the location. What build tool are you using ?

Comment: I am using MAVEN is that what you are asking?

Comment: the resources should be in src/main/resources, not in src/main/webapp/resources. just saying

Comment: Even when i modify a file in src/main/resources and then deploy it, it still gets overwritten...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include the same in the war file whenever you do a build, then do have a look at the following links :

[Including-excluding-files-from-war](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html)
[More detail info here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html)

Comment: I tried using them but i couldn't put them to any use... I will update my question with what i have tried

Comment: Hey kunal, from the pom configuration file you have posted, it looks like you are excluding resources from the build.

Comment: Isn't it what i'm suposed to do? I mean i want my resources files to remain intact whenever i deploy my app to the live server

Comment: use "includes" and the path to the directory to include the resources whenever you build and deploy.